# jQuery Lazy plugin - loading all images at once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, lazy-loading

So I'm trying to use the jQuery Lazy plugin for my photography site to lazy load my images as the user scrolls down the page. The problem is, the plugin is loading all the images at once instead of just when they come into view like it supposed to do. Does anyone have experience with this plugin or know what's going on? You can see my test site at [photography-test.timothygrindall.com](https://photography-test.timothygrindall.com).

Here's the code for the page:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Photography by Timothy Grindall</title>

        <link href="/css/style.css?v=0.1" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">

        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Amiri|Cormorant+Garamond|Nanum+Myeongjo|Noto+Serif|PT+Serif&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="description" content="Photography by Timothy Grindall">
        <meta name="keywords" content="photography, landscape, portrait, Timothy, Grindall, Washington">

        <meta name="author" content="Timothy Grindall">

        <meta charset="utf-8">

        <!-- no favicon right now -->
        <!-- <link rel="icon" href="/images/favicon.png" type="image/png"> -->

        <!-- scripts for lazy image loading -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.lazy.min.js"></script>

        <!-- script to call lazy loading -->
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            $(function() {
                $('.lazy').Lazy({
                    effect: 'fadeIn',
                    effectTime: 500,
                    visibleOnly: true,
                    onError: function(element) {
                        console.log('Error loading ' + element[0].src);
                    },
                    afterLoad: function(element) {
                        console.log('Loaded ' + element[0].src);
                        // console.log(element);
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>

        <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
        <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-7203249-8"></script>
        <script>
          window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
          function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
          gtag('js', new Date());

          gtag('config', 'UA-7203249-8');
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="top-wrapper">
            <div class="sidebar">
                <h2>Timothy Grindall</h2>
                <ul class="sidebar-menu">
                    <li><a href="/">Portfolio</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://wordpress.timothygrindall.com/">Blog</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div><div class="main">
                <p>I'm a Washington based photographer who has been taking pictures for years as an amateur but only recently decided to do it professionally. Below you will see some of my best images.</p>
                <!-- <br />
                <p>You can see my blog to the left which doesn't have very many posts on photography yet but I'm planning on writing some soon.</p>
                <br />
                <p>My Equipment is an old hand-me-down Nikon D3100 and some cheaper lenses covering 12-200mm. But my 35mm prime is my favorite.</p> -->
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="gallery-wrapper">
            <div class="gallery">
                <div class="column">
                    <img class="lazy thumbnail" data-src="images/78690010_small.jpg"><img class="lazy thumbnail" data-src="small_images/_CSC4458.jpg"><img class="lazy thumbnail" data-src="small_images/_DSC0023.jpg"><img class="lazy thumbnail" data-src="small_images/_DSC0032.jpg"><img class="lazy thumbnail" data-src="small_images/_DSC0042.jpg"><img class="lazy thumbnail" data-src="small_images/_DSC0043.jpg"><img class="lazy thumbnail" data-src="small_images/_DSC0044.jpg"><img class="lazy thumbnail" data-src="small_images/_DSC0044-2.jpg"><img class="lazy thumbnail" data-src="small_images/_DSC0069.jpg"><img class="lazy thumbnail" data-src="small_images/_DSC0100.jpg"><img class="lazy thumbnail" data-src="small_images/_DSC0205.jpg"><img class="lazy thumbnail" data-src="small_images/_DSC0288.jpg"><img class="lazy thumbnail" data-src="small_images/_DSC0715.jpg"><img class="lazy thumbnail" data-src="small_images/_DSC0771.jpg"><img class="lazy thumbnail" data-src="small_images/_DSC1613.jpg"><img class="lazy thumbnail" data-src="small_images/_DSC1919.jpg"><img class="lazy thumbnail" data-src="small_images/_DSC1937.jpg"><img class="lazy thumbnail" data-src="small_images/_DSC1947.jpg"><img class="lazy thumbnail" data-src="small_images/DSC_0061.jpg">
                </div>
                <!--<div class="column">
                    <img class="lazy thumbnail" data-src="small_images/_DSC1967.jpg"><img class="lazy thumbnail" data-src="small_images/_DSC1971.jpg"><img class="lazy thumbnail" data-src="small_images/_DSC2047.jpg"><img class="lazy thumbnail" data-src="small_images/_DSC2072.jpg"><img class="lazy thumbnail" data-src="small_images/_DSC2103.jpg"><img class="lazy thumbnail" data-src="small_images/_DSC2197.jpg"><img class="lazy thumbnail" data-src="small_images/_DSC2259-edit-2.jpg"><img class="lazy thumbnail" data-src="small_images/_DSC2667.jpg"><img class="lazy thumbnail" data-src="small_images/_DSC2767.jpg"><img class="lazy thumbnail" data-src="small_images/_DSC2950-2.jpg"><img class="lazy thumbnail" data-src="small_images/_DSC3168.jpg"><img class="lazy thumbnail" data-src="small_images/_DSC3185.jpg"><img class="lazy thumbnail" data-src="small_images/_DSC3215.jpg"><img class="lazy thumbnail" data-src="small_images/_DSC3219.jpg"><img class="lazy thumbnail" data-src="small_images/_DSC3232.jpg"><img class="lazy thumbnail" data-src="small_images/_DSC3303.jpg"><img class="lazy thumbnail" data-src="small_images/_DSC3314.jpg"><img class="lazy thumbnail" data-src="small_images/_DSC3345.jpg"><img class="lazy thumbnail" data-src="small_images/render-2_contrast.jpg">
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <img class="lazy thumbnail" data-src="small_images/_DSC3377.jpg"><img class="lazy thumbnail" data-src="small_images/_DSC4249-2.jpg"><img class="lazy thumbnail" data-src="small_images/_DSC4428.jpg"><img class="lazy thumbnail" data-src="small_images/_DSC4596.jpg"><img class="lazy thumbnail" data-src="small_images/_DSC4671.jpg"><img class="lazy thumbnail" data-src="small_images/DSC_0061.jpg"><img class="lazy thumbnail" data-src="small_images/DSC_0754.jpg"><img class="lazy thumbnail" data-src="small_images/DSC_0792.jpg"><img class="lazy thumbnail" data-src="small_images/DSC_1914.jpg"><img class="lazy thumbnail" data-src="small_images/DSC_3384.jpg"><img class="lazy thumbnail" data-src="small_images/DSC_4006.jpg"><img class="lazy thumbnail" data-src="small_images/DSC_5035.jpg"><img class="lazy thumbnail" data-src="small_images/DSC_5511.jpg"><img class="lazy thumbnail" data-src="small_images/DSC_5519.jpg"><img class="lazy thumbnail" data-src="small_images/DSC_5894.jpg"><img class="lazy thumbnail" data-src="small_images/DSC_8355.jpg"><img class="lazy thumbnail" data-src="small_images/DSC_8621.jpg">
                </div>-->
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer-wrapper">
            <div class="footer">&copy; Copyright 2019 Timothy Grindall</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

the html is simply a list of image tags with the class 'lazy' and the attribute 'data-src' as the image to be downloaded.

You can see the documentation for the plugin at http://jquery.eisbehr.de/lazy/.

I actually did get it to work for a minute but then I changed something and it started loading all the images at once again. So I changed it back but still no difference. The changes was just limiting the images to one column by commenting out the images in the second and third columns. Also, the lazy loading only worked when I uploaded the site to my live server for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

According to the test site the plugin is working correctly and is lazy loading the images on first load. You are probably confused because after the first load the images are already saved in the browser's cache so they load instantly.

Comment: At first thought it seems this is right, but when I hit shift-f5 to reload the page including the cache it still loads all the images at once. It Also does the same thing when I opened the site on a different browser which I hadn't opened it on before and on my phone which I had cleared the cache data from.

Comment: Actually, after further testing I'm convinced you are right. It does appear to be working.